# Foot with random weight that I can't erase and half of body immune to weight paint?

Tags: weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

First time Blender user here, my model's right foot seems to have weight that I didn't put there. In fact, that entire half of the body seems to be immune to weight paint so I can't get it off. I believe I parented the bones and body with automatic weights and are using the mirror modifier on the X axis. Lastly, when moving both feet the same way the 2 feet seem to move the same way anyway so maybe this isn't a problem, but I still want to know what's causing this, what to do about it, and if I should do something about it.

[image: Foot from front view] [image: Foot from side view] [image: Showcase of half of body that can and can not be weight painted] [image: Outliner window (I think?), edited in after initial post as requested by user Marty Fouts]

Comment: Your screenshot would be more useful if you opened up the right side so we can see the outliner but more importantly the properties editor, but as a guess I'd say that you have mirrored rig or body.  Is that the case?

Comment: Apply the mirror modifier and make sure the right bones end in .R and the left bones end in .L